# collectionviews in tableview selection

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uicollectionview

i added my UICollectionView to the UITableViewCell (objective c), and the data is showing correctly in the collectionviews inside the tableview, the selection in the same collectionview is working as it expected ; the problem i have is:

if the user select one cell in collectionview (a)  the label backgroundcolor of this cell is set to red

when the user select one cell in collectionview (b)  the label backgroundcolor of this cell is set to red but the backgroundcolor of the previous selected cell in collectionview a is still
in red !

my question is how can i set clearColor to the previous selected cell ?

please help thank you

nb: the data and the number of collectionview are dynamic

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   if(self.selectedIndex == indexPath.item)
                             {
                                                                      cell.label.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
                                 }
                  
                             else
                             {
                                cell.label.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
                                 
                             }
}



- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
     self.selectedIndex = indexPath.row;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you record or mark the state in UI, sometimes it's not simple way.
I suggest store the state in data model, and the cell's appearance is based on the data model, once the data model change, refresh the corresponding cell, that will work.
Here is a simple example:
[image]

in ViewController.m
[image]

[image]
in XXCellDataModel.h
[image]
in XXCollectionViewCell.h
[image]
in XXCollectionViewCell.m
[image]

Comment: thanks for responding, please if you have an example it will be more clearer for me, thank you

Comment: thanks a lot for your help, I will try your solution thank you

Comment: hello; I get this error when using your code [__NSDictionaryI selected]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Comment: are your data model a NSDictionary? if you use NSDictionary, you should use setter or getter by 'setObjectForKey:' , 'objectForKey:'